# Python: Drop Rows With NaNs When Memory Constrained

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have 3 numpy arrays [A,B,C] they all have same number of rows but different number of columns. I need to drop the rows from all arrays if any of the arrays have a nan or inf on that row. I need to use as little memory as possible.

for example, if the first row of A has a nan or inf, I need to drop the first row of A,B,C

I considered making them into one big pandas data frame and then using dropna.But that takes up a lot of ram.

Comment: I don't think you can be anymore memory frugal than to generate a mask of the rows that you want to keep (either boolean or a list of indices), and make a copy of each array, `A = A[I,:]`.

Comment: Is there a way I could do this in batches to reduce memory overhead?

Comment: Once you've constructed the mask, I don't see how a 'batch' operation would save memory overhead.  I don't think it needs to construct intermediate temporary arrays.  It just needs to allocate space for the new array, copy the data, change a variable pointer, and garbage collect the old array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `isfinite()` and `sum(axis=-1)`:

```
import numpy as np

def random_with_nan_and_inf(shape, count):
    a = np.random.rand(*shape)
    idx = [np.random.randint(0, n, count) for n in shape]
    a[idx] = ([np.nan, np.inf] * count)[:count]
    return a

a = random_with_nan_and_inf((100, 3), 5)
b = random_with_nan_and_inf((100, 4), 10)
c = random_with_nan_and_inf((100, 5), 15)

mask = np.isfinite(a.sum(-1) + b.sum(-1) + c.sum(-1))
a2, b2, c2 = a[mask], b[mask], c[mask]
```

Comment: @HYRY: Any special reason why you used `axis=-1` as opposed to `axis=1`?

Comment: @Ewerton, there is no special reason.